# Хранение таблицы в БД

Tags: php, mysql

Хочу сделать что-то типа журнала посещений. Я выберу нужные мне чекбоксы и нажму отправить.

Вопрос следующий, как правильнее потом будет всё это занести в бд? 
создавать для каждого человека ячейку и для каждого дня столбец и потом это всё другие сохранять? или же есть другие способы хранения таких таблиц?

```
<tr>
    <td>ФИО</td>
    <td><label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-success"> <input type="checkbox" checked><span></span></label></td>
    <td><label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-success"> <input type="checkbox" checked><span></span></label></td>
    <td><label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-success"> <input type="checkbox" checked><span></span></label></td>
    <td><label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-success"> <input type="checkbox" checked><span></span></label></td>
    <td><label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-success"> <input type="checkbox" checked><span></span></label></td>
    <td><label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-success"> <input type="checkbox" checked><span></span></label></td>
    <td><label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-success"> <input type="checkbox" checked><span></span></label></td>
    <td><label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-success"> <input type="checkbox" checked><span></span></label></td>
    <td><label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-success"> <input type="checkbox" checked><span></span></label></td>
</tr>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В БД должны быть созданы две таблицы. 
В одной будут храниться данные о ФИО (сотрудники, студенты, просто люди и их данные), а в другой собственно даты (посещения, отсутствия или что там у вас).
Сводить это все в одну таблицу будете запросом.

P.S. Надеюсь правильно понял ворпрос и интересует структура БД больше, чем PHP

Comment: А можно пример такого запроса?

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE journal (name VARCHAR(255), present DATE);
```

Добавить присутствие для Пети Васечкина (если совсем просто)

```
$name = 'Петя Васечкин';
$dates = ['2017.10.01', '2017.10.02', '2017.09.23']; //массив дат, когда он присутствовал
$date = $dates[0];

$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO journal (name, present) VALUES(?,?)');
$stmt->bind_params('ss', $name, $date);

foreach($dates as $date){
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Все дни, когда Петя Васечкин присутствовал

```
SELECT present WHERE name='Петя Васечкин';
```